# Create SQL Server User and grant select permissions to one schema only

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication

I am trying to create a very simple user in Azure Sql Server what will have only "SELECT" permissions only to one schema "my_data"

I am trying

```
CREATE LOGIN dataReaderUser WITH PASSWORD = '1';
go
CREATE USER dataReaderUser FOR LOGIN dataReaderUser;
go
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: my_data TO dataReaderUser
```

then trying to use connection string in ADO.NET

```
Data Source=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_DB;User ID=dataReaderUser;Password=1
```

It can't even login! What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: My SQL Server didn't have SQL Service authentication on, only windows authentication. It started working once enabled windows and SQL Service authentication. Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't grant authorization on the db for the user?

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::yourDB TO dataReaderUser;
```